# Issues Serial Port Watch using threads with an event loop and QSocketNotifiers

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt4

I asked this question yesterday since I wasn't receiving any data but strangely when I used wait in the destructor I started receveing notification from `QSocketNotifier`. The rest of the question is same. Can someone suggest something?
I have created a sample application from where separate thread is started to read and process data from serial port. `QSocketNotifier` is used for detecting whether data has arrived on the serial ports or not. I start an event loop using `exec()` statement in run function of thread. But while running the application only once the socket notifier has worked, the signal for serial port activation is never generated. And once when it was generated it was generated very fast and wasn't equivalent to the frame rate of sending device.

Here is a brief code sample for serial communicator thread:

SerialPortWatchOne.cpp

```
//constructor
klass::klass()
{
//setport configuration
//miscellaneous initialization
QSocketNotifier* notifier = new QSocketNotifier(mPort->GetFileDescriptor, QSocketNotifier::Read,this);
connect(notifier,SIGNAL(activated(int)),this,SLOT(ReadAndProcessData()));
}

void klass::run()
{
exec();  //this starts an event loop where by Qt signal handling is enabled
}

void klass::ReadAndProcessData()
{
      FlushBuf();      
      int bytes_read=mPort->ReadPort(mBuf,1000);
      if(bytes_read>0)
         //Process data
}

~klass::klass()
{
//desctruction code;
wait();  //so that thread cleanly releases all resources before exit
}
```

Note: klass is a thread and a member of GUI thread and is instantiated in the GUI thread c'tor. periodically GUI updates its widgets with data from klass thread.

Can anyone suggest as what the issue is? Has someone done this before.

Comment: You seem to be missing a description of the problem. Don't assume that people will have read your previous quesion (or would want to). Better to make this question complete

Comment: This is the exact question I asked yesterday with only the first couple of lines which were a result of my work done today. If there is anything more which is not clear just point it out. I have made it amply clear from my side

Answer (score 0):

Only thing that comes to mind is that you're using `QSocketNotifier * socketNotifier` without an event loop running in the `socketNotifier->thread()` thread. If no event loop is running, you'll get no event handling. No event handling means no signals fired from `QSocketNotifier`. But if you're using a separate thread, you might want to use blocking I/O calls anyway.